# Is it possible to replace a parent class?

Tags: c++

If I have a class that's inheriting from another, is it possible to replace the inherited class in the child? I've got a demo of what I'm trying to do below,  but I'm not sure the syntax.

```
#include <iostream>

class singleNum
{
public:
    int m_a;
    singleNum(int a)
    {
        std::cout << "SETUP" << std::endl;
        m_a = a;
    }
    ~singleNum()
    {
        std::cout << "CLOSEDOWN" << std::endl;
    }
};


class inheritor : public singleNum
{
public:
    inheritor(int a) : singleNum(a) {};
    reset(int b)
    {
        singleNum::this = *singleNum(b);
    }

};


int main()
{
    inheritor z(5);
    std::cout << z.m_a << std::endl;
    z.reset(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "replace"? We cannot deduce that from code that, by your own admission, does not actually achieve your goal.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition deliberate slicing, if I understood correctly.

Comment: At runtime, remove the parent implementation, and substitute a newly constructed one.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want want to change in the child class the properties of the parent class. I would implement this feature in a method of the parent class. Either a public method or a protected method that is then reimplemented as public by the child class.

Comment: Seems like a design smell, but is there something wrong with `op=`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

You cannot exchange or reset the base class. If it had a reset method of it's own, you could call this, but you cannot call the constructor again.

If you want to do this, you should [favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). You can then create a completely new instance of the inner composition class and replace your existing instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your current demo isn't hard to implement, but you'll need to modify the parent class:

```
#include <iostream>

class singleNum
{
public:
    int m_a;
    singleNum(int a)
    {
        std::cout << "SETUP" << std::endl;
        reset(a);
    }
    ~singleNum()
    {
        std::cout << "CLOSEDOWN" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void reset(int b)
    {
        m_a = b;
    }
};


class inheritor : public singleNum
{
public:
    inheritor(int a) : singleNum(a) {}
    void reset(int b) override
    {
        singleNum::reset(b);
    }

};


int main()
{
    inheritor z(5);
    std::cout << z.m_a << std::endl;
    z.reset(5);
    return 0;
}
```

But this is the closest you will get to "replacing the base class". If your case is different than the demo presented and you *need* to call the base class constructor on an already constructed derived object then no, this is not doable.